# Css developer i want to solve slick nav mobile menu issue. only for iphone

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, responsive-design, slicknav

i have just create a mobile menu with some transition. i am using slick nav mobile menu but mobile menu icon not showing in iphone all other device works perfectly.

this is my project c2ma.it-/-pt-/- please remove - from url. i am not able to find why that icon hidden behind that images. unable to find please reply on same

i have added below css to show mobile menu icon

```
.slicknav_menu {
background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
float: right;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 30px; }
```

Normally android showing this but iphone is not [image: mobile menu not showing in iphone]

Comment: The css you posted does not reference an image or icon. Can you please post more of your code

Comment: i have upload image which is normally show in any android phone.

Comment: He supplied the link above, Aidan. I checked your link in two iphone emulators and it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add

```
z-index:9999;
```

To your css and see if that will make it display. The element could be hidden behind the image.

Comment: yes, i have try that but not work... also in firefox if you check that is not clickable but if you check in chrome it work well and in android device also.